# NERDTree: Autocmd error vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I am trying to add NERDTree to my RHEL machine by appending following lines in .vimrc after placing NERD_tree.vim in plugin folder.

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

The problem is that I am able to run it using these commands in Mac but RHEL throws this error:

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree
```

Can somebody help me resolve this error?

Comment: Is the plugin properly installed; i.e. does `:NERDTree` work when you type it after starting Vim (in RHEL)?

Comment: No, it gives Not an editor command. But, I used the same steps while I was doing it in mac.

Comment: "appending following lines after placing .vim in plugin folder" sounds weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `:NERDTree` also doesn't work, that means that the plugin isn't properly installed.

To troubleshoot, check the output of `:scriptnames`; it must list `.../plugin/NERD_tree.vim` (in the location where you've put it), and verify the value of `'runtimepath'`, especially if you use a plugin manager (like Pathogen, Vundle, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the package manager [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) isn't installed yet.

Run:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

then add the following lines to `.vimrc`:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```